# C# class code with data from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, class

Hello and thanks taking your time to help me.

When a user login hes User id is stored in a session, and when he enters my Survey page. I want to the page to display the Surveys that is avalible to him.

My Database Diagram:
[image]

I tried to Write the code so First it checks if there is any relations between the user and the surveys in the RelationShip table. I have made sure that part works with debugging because it returns 1 since there is 1 user and one survey + the relation with the correct information.

But it cant write the last part like this: **lstItem = db.Survey.Where(x => x.ID == relation).ToList();** so it returns the Correct Survey to my repeater. Since there might be more Surveys avaliple to a user.

My class Code:

```
public class Surveys
{
public static List<Survey> getAll(int id)
{
    List<Survey> lstItem = new List<Survey>();
    using (KONE_Entities db = new KONE_Entities())
    {
        List<User_Survey_Relation> relation = new List<User_Survey_Relation>();

        relation = db.User_Survey_Relation.Where(i => i.UserID == id).ToList();

        if (relation != null)
        {
            lstItem = db.Survey.Where(x => x.ID == relation).ToList();
        }
    }

    return lstItem;
}
}
```

My C# code that binds it to the repeater:

```
private void BindSurvey()
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());
    rpSurveys.DataSource = Surveys.getAll(id);
    rpSurveys.DataBind();
}
```

So to Clarify what Im asking for/ need help with: My Code will not return the Survey or Surveys that has a relation with the user that is logged on to the site.

Thanks for your time and I hope you can help me.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. It isn't clear at all (at least to me).

Comment: The code will not return the information about the survey or surveys(if there is more than 1) back to the repeater.

Comment: OK, after re-reading a few times I can see your issue. Your query on `User_Survey_Relation` returns a list of rows from that table. However, in your second query you try and compare those rows with an ID, which obviously won't work. You need to select the ID in your first query. Your second query will need to change too.

Comment: lstItem = db.Survey.Where(x => x.ID == relation).ToList();   you are equating a list and a single variable that's impossible,IDE should have thrown you an error isnt it??

Comment: @DanielKelley Thanks for your time in reading it. Could you maybe write a surgestion code so i can try it out?

Comment: @Thi49 The code you posted is just some code i wrote to try explain/show what I would like it to do

Comment: @user3387502 Posted an answer but looks like you got a working solution anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare individual relation values and then add the result to lstItem .

```
foreach(User_Survey_Relation relatSingle in relation){
    lstItem.addRange(db.Survey.Where(x => x.ID == relatSingle.SurveyID).ToList());
}
}
```

Sorry...dude ...compared the whole class,i have edited it...please check if surveyId has to be compared or Id

Comment: the x.ID == relatsingle returns this error: operator '==' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int' and 'User_Survey_Relation'

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the comments what is wrong with your logic. In terms of how best to solve it, I believe your best option is to join your tables in a single query rather than running 2 queries. The SQL syntax would be:

```
select s.*
from Survey s
inner join User_Survey_Relation usr on s.ID = usr.SurveyID
where usr.UserID = id
```

Translating this to LINQ becomes (this is rough - I don't have VS to test):

```
lstItem = (from db.Survey in survey 
          join db.User_Survey_Relation in relation on survey.ID 
              equals relation.SurveyID 
          where relation.UserID = id
          select survey).ToList();
```

Like I say, you may need to play around with this to iron out any wrinkles. Hopefully you get the idea though.